# Did Erdős prove there are two primes $4a+1, 4b+3$ between between $n$ and $2n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChoquetTheory.html

Is the claim in the link true? Here's the reference given there:

[https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1934-01.pdf)

> Erdős proved that there exist at least one prime $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and at least one prime $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ between $n$ and $2n$ for all $n>6$.
>
> References:
> *Erdős, P. "A Theorem of Sylvester and Schur." J. London Math. Soc. 9, 282-288, 1934.*

Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Bertrand%27s_postulate#Dubious_statement

My question:

> Can you find the proof of this in the given pdf (maybe somewhere else)?

Comment: Erdős did not prove or claim that there were twin primes between $n$ and $2n$. One “prime of the form $4k+1$” and one “prime of the form $4k+3$” do not have to be of those forms with the same value of $k$. This is just a question of what it means in mathematical English to say a number is “of the form ...”

Comment: @SteveKass Of course, the question is whether there exist two primes one congruent to $1$ and the other congruent to $3$ mod $4$. See the title of my question. It was stated in a bit ambiguous way there, but it's clear to me what was meant.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding! I’m not sure I’m up to answering your actual question, but I hope someone is.

Comment: It's been answered on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219999/did-erd%C5%91s-prove-there-are-two-primes-4a1-4b3-between-between-n-and-2n/220001#220001